# How do I run fzf#run not in full screen and yet store the output into a variable?

Tags: fzf

(I've installed [`fzf`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) and added `Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'do': { -> fzf#install() } }` in my vimrc, as suggested in the [readme](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/README-VIM.md).)

If I run `:let xxx = fzf#run({'source': 'ps -e'})`, `fzf` correctly opens up and I can filter the entries and select one them by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Doing so populates the variable `xxx` with whatever I selected via `fzf`.

However, plain `fzf#run` opens `fzf` at full scree, which I don't like.

Therefore, I tried `:let xxx = fzf#run(fzf#wrap({'source': 'ps -e'}))`, but I must have misunderstood what `fzf#wrap` is for and how I can use it, because the previous command runs `fzf` the correct way (i.e. not in full screen), but doesn't store the output into `xxx`; it rather treats it as a file to be `:edit`ed.

Comment: Mention what plugin you're using, please.

Comment: Please, @kadekai, see updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fzf#wrap` function returns a table of default options, along with what you provided to it (`{'source': 'ps -e'}` in your example). `fzf#run` function uses `sink` value of the options table to determine what to do with the selected entry. The default value of `sink` is `edit` (I think; I haven't actually seen it in the code yet; I'm looking still). What you can do is define your own function and do what you want with the FZF entry.

```
func! MyFunc(entry)
  let g:xxx = a:entry
endfunc
```

Then you can call `fzf#run` in the following manner.

```
:call fzf#run(fzf#wrap({'source': 'ps -e', 'sink': function('MyFunc')}))
:echo g:xxx
```

---

Note: I have no idea how you managed to populate variable `xxx` in your first example. I can't reproduce it and the source code says (as far as I can see) it shouldn't happen. `fzf#run` [returns an empty table](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/4993d19466d5f3ac127de5c0c461cde7ef1894d7/plugin/fzf.vim#L928).

Comment: Maybe it is worth a bug report :/ I'll do in the evening

Comment: However, it looks to me that `fzf#run` does return things. The link you provided is to the `return` statement of `s:execute_term`.

Comment: @Enlico yes it is, but [`fzf#run` returns the return value of `s:execute_term`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/4993d19466d5f3ac127de5c0c461cde7ef1894d7/plugin/fzf.vim#L525). And [here is junegunn's response](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/2916) to our question. He suggests using `sink` option, which is what I suggested. So I'd appreciate it if you marked this answer correct (unless you don't think it's correct, of course).

Comment: Accepted the suggestion of using `sink`. However I've truly not understood what's wrong `fzf#run`'s return.

Comment: Have you read through junegunn's response. He has done a good job explaining it. But it boils down to this: due to difference in different systems (vim vs neovim, windows vs linux, etc.), it's difficult to code `fzf#run` in a way that it behaves the same in every system. What the difficulties are, you'll have to go through the source code.

Comment: Yes, I have read read that. But not truly understood the answer. I've commented there.